# Wildcard SSL not working for subdomains

Tags: ssl, ip, domain, https, subdomain

I have a wildcard SSL for my website, I want to access my site using any subdomain like abc.immersive.com,xyz.immersive.com etc.
I tried to ping these sites, its pinging successfully and pointing to my site IP but I cannot access it through this URL. I have added DNS record for wildcard subdomain (*.immersive.com).

**P.S.** My domain/SSL is through MyDomain.

Comment: The site is (currently?) not reachable (not a SSL problem). It is unclear what certificate this site actually provides so no help can be given what is wrong. Also "not working" is not a usable error message to debug the problem, please add all the error details to your question.

Comment: Your site is correctly sending 301 redirects on HTTP, but HTTPS is timing out. Check your firewall.

Comment: Are you using Google Managed SSL Certificates? If yes, wildcards are not supported

Answer (score 1):

you may check with your web service provider.
It is redirecting to different url.